# How to encrypt response payload

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an API which send some sensitive information to the client.

I need to encrypt outgoing response data using the API Manager. How can I encrypt the outgoing response data?

How to encrypt response payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypting payload is not supported out-of-the-box. As mentioned by @ycr, it has to be implemented as a custom mediator and then applied to the Out Sequence. However, while this is possible, we are not recommending this method because using a custom payload encrypter would impact API Manager performance and add considerable overhead to the overall performance.

Refer to this documentation[1] for further information about writing a custom handler.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/extending-api-manager/extending-gateway/writing-custom-handlers/

A side note - if you are using the HTTPS protocol in the transport layer, the message payload has already been encrypted throughout the communication. Therefore message interception by a third-party would not be possible in that scenario.

Comment: Have we done any performance testing on this for both Symmetric and Asymmetric encryption? Any useful information for us to get an understanding on how much of a performance impact we are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

If you need something more than TLS encryption, you may have to implement a custom mediator to do encryption in API Manager. For example, you can use a Symmetric algorithm like AES to encrypt the payload and send it back to the client. [Here](https://github.com/yasassri/wso2-aes-mediator) is a sample Custom Mediator that does AES Encryption. Once you develop and deploy the Mediator you can engage it using a custom mediation policy as explained [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-policies/regular-gateway-policies/adding-a-class-mediator/).

Having said that, I think your Backend is the best place to encrypt the data as that's the source/origin of data.